# NBodySimulation: custom pairwise potential

Tags: differential-equations, version-12

I'm trying to define a [Lennard-Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) potential in 2D for [`NBodySimulation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NBodySimulation.html)

```
\[Epsilon] = 1; rm = 1;

LJ[b1_, b2_] := 
 With[{rd = rm/EuclideanDistance[b1["Position"], b2["Position"]]},
  \[Epsilon]*(rd^12 - 2*rd^6)
  ]


data = NBodySimulation[
   <|
    "PairwisePotential" -> LJ
    |>,
   {
    <|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {-0.6, 1}, "Velocity" -> {0., 0}|>,
    <|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {0.6, -1}, "Velocity" -> {0., 0}|>
    },
   10
   ];
```

This gives the following error:

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

I've seen similar questions on this site relating to `NDSolve`. Accord to these to issue could be either with the initial conditions, or the function given to `NDSolve`.

Here, the issue is clearly not with the initial conditions, as replacing `LJ` with `"Harmonic"` works perfectly:

```
data = NBodySimulation[
   <|
    "PairwisePotential" -> "Harmonic"
    |>,
   {
    <|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {-0.6, 1}, "Velocity" -> {0., 0}|>,
    <|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {0.6, -1}, 
     "Velocity" -> {0., 0}|>
    },
   10
   ];
```

So maybe `NDSolve` doesn't like `EuclideanDistance`. However when I calculate the distance manually, I still run into error messages:

```
LJ[b1_, b2_] := 
 With[{rd = 
    1/((b1["Position"][[1]] - 
         b2["Position"][[1]])^2 + (b1["Position"][[2]] - 
         b2["Position"][[2]])^2)},
  \[Epsilon]*(rd^6 - 2*rd^3)
  ]
```

In this case `NBodySimulation[...]` gives the following error:

```
Part::partw: Part 2 of q1[t] does not exist.
Part::partw: Part 2 of q2[t] does not exist.
```

Based on this I think that `b1["Position"]` passed to my potential function is not really a vector, or is not evaluated when I'm trying to reference its components. But then how possibly can I implement a 2D or 3D potential for `NBodySimulation`?

Comment: FWIW:  Using `Norm` to compute the distance in the denominator of `rd` works fine...i.e.: `rd = rm/Norm[b1["Position"] - b2["Position"]]`

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier You're correct, thank you so much! Bit off-topic, but could you explain  why `Norm` works and my other two versions don't, more specifically, why I can't reference components of the position vectors?

Comment: Try replacing your function with `LJ[b1_, b2_] := 
 With[{rd = rm/Norm[b1["Position"] - b2["Position"]]}, 
  Print[b1]; \[Epsilon]*(rd^12 - 2*rd^6)]` You'll notice that `b1` is a Symbol, not a vector.  Although I'm not sure why `EuclideanDistance` should fail to work in that case.